# How do I turn a turtle in our teams favor?

Tags: league-of-legends

If we're being pushed super hard by the enemy team and we're forced to turtle, what is the best way to take advantage of this situation and make sure we can still turn this match around.

Answer (score 1):

Farm.

As long as you aren't being dove or engaged on, the position is not as terrible as it seems.  If an inhibitor is down, all of your lanes will push on you naturally, meaning your team will get farm and your opponents will only get some.  However, your team must pay attention to objectives such as Baron and perhaps Blue Buff depending on your team.

In short, get your AD carry (most probably) to farm as hard as possible if he/she's not 6 items already and keep clearing the waves.  Normal teamfight strategy then applies (group, don't get caught, try to single out and catch an enemy, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Agreed. Farm.

If it's late in the game and the death timer is really high, winning a team exchange when turtling, can be a game changer. This is more apparent in 3v3 but still doable in 5v5 especially if you have a champ that can move around the map fast.